# AngularJS dropdown list loses content after item selected

Tags: c#, javascript, http, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net WebAPI project that I run from VS that supplies data in the form of JSON to my Angular project. I get the data from the webapi via an $http.get call like so:

```
function CarController($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:1246/api/values')
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             $scope.carSet = data;
         })
         .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             $scope.error = status;
             alert("You be broken buddy!");
         });
}
```

Then the carSet is bound in the html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="CarController">
        <select data-ng-model="carSet" onchange="DataChanged()" data-ng-options="c.Color for c in carSet"></select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works great. I get my list. The first entry is blank and that is ok for now.

THE PROBLEM:
When I select any of the items in the dropdown list, the entire list is cleared out and there are no more items to select from?? Whaaaaat! At this point I am clearly frustrated.  This behavior only happens when I use the $http mechanism to retrieve data from the WebApi.  It does not happen if I use the $http.get to retrieve json data from a file or other locally created data stores.  I just need a simple dropdown list that will allow me to use it's selected values for filtering other data (another db call.)

I would show you pics.. but this is my very first post.. and well.... I can't.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: can you create a plunker that demonstrates this problem

Comment: what is `onchange="DataChanged()"` for? Not a good idea using native change inline event handlers in angular. Use `ng-change`, however code doesn't have that function . Also **`$scope = {};`** looks like a terrible idea

Comment: DataChanged() was just a handler to to break the code when the combo collapsed after selection.  Then I could step into the remaining code to try and figure out what was happening. Yeah, not sure how to model a webapi return in plunker, since using $http to retrieve data from static sources seems to work fine. It's the dynamic part that doesn't work.

Comment: I would recommend not using $scope = {};, it is a much better practice to user controllerAs. As for what is happening, to get a good understanding, looks like you are having a storage issue, and storing the carset is the way to go, such as, this.carset = data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `data-ng-model="carSet"` to something different e.g. `data-ng-model="carChosenColor"` and it will work fine.

Then in `$scope.carChosenColor` will store the chosen value.

Comment: Ok, this is sort of right. Good enough of a hint to make it work so you win! Yea! Ultimately I changed the code from data-ng-model="carSet" to data-ng-model="carSet.Color" and that worked. This little bit drove me crazy today. A big thanks to you Artur!